# On Duplicate Key Update Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am using Google SQL. I have a program which user can change the data of the database if there is same username in the database. User is using POST to post their information to the database. After refer to few StackOverFlow question and answer, I managed to reach the code below but it is not working.

```
try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
    String sql = "INSERT INTO 'data' ('username', 'UUID', 'tenant_id', 'site_id')" 
    + "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)" 
    + "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" 
    + "UUID = VALUES(UUID), tenant_id = VALUES(tenant_id), site_id = VALUES(site_id)";
    stat = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    stat.setString(1, UserName1);
    stat.setString(2, UUID1);
    stat.setString(3, Tenant_ID1);
    stat.setString(4, Site_ID1);
    stat.executeUpdate();
    stat.close();
    conn.close();
}
```

My code able to work without the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` but after add on that, it become unable to work. I am still new to Java and SQL and ready to accept any opinions from user here. Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: what is the error you are getting now

Comment: Hi @MohanaPriyan I not getting any error. I just unable to change the data in the database when the username is the same.

Comment: i think,You need to give space after " on duplicate key Update  "

Comment: You need a space between `UPDATE" 
    + " UUID`

Comment: Hi @MohanaPriyan I tried your advice and it is not working.

Comment: Hi @YCF_L I tried your advice also and it is not working.

Comment: can u show us your error please?

Comment: Hi @YCF_L I don't have error. I unable to change the data in the database with the same username using above code.

Comment: Hi. MohanaPriyan and YCF_L First I wish to apologize for not doing further troubleshooting before say that both of your answers are not working. After I do some troubleshooting, I realized the mistakes are `'data' ('username', 'UUID', 'tenant_id', 'site_id')` should be `data(username, UUID, tenant_id, site_id)` and also the space between UPDATE and UUID. I feel very sorry and thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @MohanaPriyan and @YCF_L advice. I managed to solve the problem. The correct code should be

`String sql = "INSERT INTO data (username, UUID, tenant_id, site_id)" 
    + "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)" 
    + "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" 
    + " UUID = VALUES(UUID), tenant_id = VALUES(tenant_id), site_id = VALUES(site_id)";`